# push if not exist in array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below model in JS . I am using angular js

```
$scope.data = {
            FocusOn: " ",
            Filters: [],
            Range: {
                From: "",
                To: ""
            }
        }
```

I have the below function :

```
$scope. addField = function ($type, $value) {
            $scope.data1 = {
                FilterName: $type,
                FilterValue: $value
            };
            if ($scope.data.Filters[$type] === undefined) {
                $scope.data.Filters.push($scope.data1);
            }
            $scope.data1 = "";
            $scope.Json = angular.toJson($scope.data);

        };
```

I want to push the **Filters** if it is not available already. How can i do this.

I have tried above but dint work. What went wrong. 
Can anyone please help me,

Thanks,

Comment: Just a tip: prefixing your function parameters with `$` is going to be confusing for other developers. When using AngularJS, only the core Angular functions are prefixed with `$` so you know what is core AngularJS functionality, and what is your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am assuming that `$scope.data.Filters` is an array of objects with a `FilterName` and `FilterValue` property.

In that case, you actually need to search the array to see if a matching object exists before inserting it, by comparing the values of the properties of the object (a deep equality check, as opposed to a shallow equality check, which `indexOf()` does).

If you use [lodash](http://lodash.com) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org), you can use the `_.findWhere()` helper to do this easily:

```
if (!_.findWhere($scope.data.Filters, $scope.data1)) {
    $scope.data.Filters.push($scope.data1);
}
```

Otherwise, you could make your own function, so your full code looks like:

```
$scope.addField = function ($type, $value) {
    $scope.data1 = {
        FilterName: $type,
        FilterValue: $value
    };
    if (!filterExists($type)) {
        $scope.data.Filters.push($scope.data1);
    }
    $scope.data1 = "";
    $scope.Json = angular.toJson($scope.data);
};

function filterExists(type) {
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.data.Filters.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($scope.data.Filters[i].FilterName === type)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Backtrack Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$scope.addField = function ($type, $value) {
        $scope.data1 = {
            FilterName: $type,
            FilterValue: $value
        };
        if ($scope.data.Filters[$type] == undefined) {
            $scope.data.Filters[$type] = $scope.data1;
        }
        $scope.data1 = "";
        $scope.Json = angular.toJson($scope.data);

    };
```